# SPBuiltInFieldId structure for BCS - is there any const for "BdcIdentity"? 

Tags: bcs, external-content-type

For SPListItem's built-in field values we have SPBuiltInFieldId class with many guids - SPBuiltInFieldId.Title and so on.

Now I am working with BCS and I can't find any built-in object for "BdcIdentity" field title for item fields in external lists. All the MSND's code-samples not so well-formed with hard-coded "BdcIdentity" string inside. So, should I cover it up in own const-static class or is there already built-in constant for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any re-usable constant for "BdcIdentity".

Using .Net Reflector I searched most of the SharePoint 2010 assemblies and found that MS seem to hard code this string inline repeatedly rather than use a constant.

The best thing for you to do is create your own constant.

Comment: Well, I used to make a research with reflecto too. And have similar result.
Ok, at this very moment I'll write a const-string and if I find out any built-in const I'll make a msg here.

Thnx a lot.